# R Studio 1.3.959 Errors in Installing Packages?

Tags: r

As I try to install tidyverse on my newly installed R Studio, with Rtools already installed, it gives me such errors. I am confused as to how I should approach this. Perhaps I have missed something fundamental?

> install.packages("tidyverse")
>
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Asus/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tidyverse_1.3.0.zip'
>
> Content type 'application/zip' length 439944 bytes (429 KB) downloaded 429 KB
>
> package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwvpGBU\downloaded_packages
>
> library(tidyverse)
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'broom', details:
>     call: loadNamespace(name)
>     error: there is no package called ‘backports’
>
> devtools::install_github("")
>
> Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
>     call: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
>     error: there is no package called ‘backports

EDIT: Phil is great, it worked

Comment: Run `install.packages("backports")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install.packages("backports") comment from Phil worked

Answer (score 0):

You could go about installing these dependencies manually as suggested in the comments. However, I would try the following:

```r
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Also see the following link for more information about the `dependencies` argument:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages